# VK, обработка сообщения

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api

Пишу простой бот ВК на С#, отвечающий в конфе от моего имени на фразу "Евгений, погода". Не пойму немного, как отлавливать прием сообщения? Не подскажите логику?

Есть метод messages.GetHistory,возвращающий N сообщений. Может мне каждый тик таймера брать 20 сообщений послених и там искать это сообщение, и удалять после того, как нашел?
Звучит очень неоптимально, но я не вижу альтернативы

Comment: Какую библиотеку Вы используете для интеграции с VK?

Comment: уже были подобные вопросы
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610009/long-polling-c

Answer (score 5):

Самый эффективный способ отлавливания новых личных сообщений **пользователя** — это [Long Poll](https://vk.com/dev/using_longpoll).

Но вообще, если у вас есть возможность поднять скрипт на бэкэнде, то тогда писать ботов следует с использованием сообществ и их личных сообщений. Для них предоставляется дополнительный функционал в виде [Callback API](https://vk.com/dev/callback_api) — эдакий аналог вэбхуков в Телеграме. То есть ВК сам будет POST-запросами сообщать вам, когда и что вашему сообществу написали в ЛС.

Answer (score 3):

Вот пример на коленке с использованием VkApi

```
  internal class Program
  {
    private static VkApi _api;

    private static void Main()
    {
      const string email = "email";
      const string pass = "password";

      _api = new VkApi();
      _api.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams
      {
        Login = email,
        Password = pass,
        Settings = Settings.Messages,
        ApplicationId = 0000 // vkAppId
      });

      Thread pollMessagesThread = new Thread(PollUnread)
      {
        IsBackground = true,
        Name = nameof(pollMessagesThread)
      };

      pollMessagesThread.Start();
      pollMessagesThread.Join(); // для теста.
    }

    private static void PollUnread()
    {
      HashSet<string> messages = new HashSet<string>(); 
      // желательно сделать expirableSet или время от времени чистить эту коллекцию
      while (true /*_shouldStop конечно же*/)
      {
        var msgs = _api?.Messages.GetHistory(new MessagesGetHistoryParams
        {
          UserId = 00000000 // Id пользователя c которым ведете диалог.
        });

        foreach (var msgsMessage in msgs.Messages)
        {
          if (!messages.Contains(msgsMessage.Body))
          {
            messages.Add(msgsMessage.Body);
            Console.WriteLine(msgsMessage.Body);
          }
        }

        Thread.Sleep(3000);
      }
    }
  }
```

**UPD:** ещё метод `PollUnread` можно переделать так что бы что то делать только в случае если есть не прочитаны сообщения:

```
private static void PollUnread()
{
  while (true /*_shouldStop конечно же*/)
  {
    var msgs = _api?.Messages.GetHistory(new MessagesGetHistoryParams
    {
      UserId = 00000000 // Id пользователя c которым ведете диалог.
    });

    if (msgs.Unread > 0)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(msgs.Messages);
      // Unreaded messages.
    }

    Thread.Sleep(3000);
  }
}
```